# SQL query to get data from two rows connected by key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a question that seems very simple to me at first but I'm relatively new to SQL and I can't solve it.

I have two tables: 'Applicants' and 'Family Units'.

Applicants:

```
ApplicantID | FirstName  
----------- | ----------  
1           | John  
2           | Mary
```

Family Units:

```
ApplicantID | UnitID| Note  
1           | 10    | Member  
2           | 10    | Mother
```

I need to bring in one table Applicant Name and Mother Name.
Mother applicantID should be determined by having same UnitID in Family Units table  and Mother Note in the same table (and other details they are not relevant here).
I tried this query:
[image]

That obviously doesn't work correct, I get applicant name instead of applicant's mother's name.
Need you help, links to articles and explanations also will be great because I feel that I'm missing something very basic.

Comment: then what's your expected output here?

Comment: I need to get Applicant name and Mother name in 1 row

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago!) and its use is discouraged

Comment: But your table doesn't point whose applicant for that mother.. i mean your given test data is not enough to give your desired output

Comment: @reds,  Mother applicantID should be determined by having same UnitID in Family Units table  and Mother Note in the same table.

Answer (score 1):

```
; with cte as
    (
    select fu.*,a.name from 
    FamilyUnit fu
    join applicant a on a.id = fu.id
    where type = 'Mother'
    )
    select a.id,a.name,c.name
    from applicant a
    join FamilyUnit fu on fu.id = a.id
    join cte c on c.unit = fu.unit
    where c.id <> a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not so sure if this is correct: just try it

```
 select * from 
 (select * from  @family_units where  note = 'member') as a
 left join
  (select * from  @family_units where  note = 'mother') as b
  on a.unitid = b.unitid
left join @applicant_table as c
 on a.ApplicantID  =c.ApplicantID
```

Test result:

```
1   10  Member  2   10  Mother  1   John
```